# Does the shape of a tangerine (a sphere pinched at the poles) have a name?

Tags: geometry, spheres, spherical-geometry

I have in mind a modified sphere which, if all longitudinal radii were equal, would just be a sphere however instead, each longitudinal radius has an increasingly smaller value than those of the ones before it. As a result, each longitudinal radius was closer to the centre than the last, in fact the drop in radius between two radii (r2 and r3, where r2 is closer to the equator) would be greater than the drop between the two radii before (r1 and r2, where r1 is the equatorial radius). Is that remotely understandable?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I think we used to call it an Oblate Spheroid in Mechanics. Isn't a better approximation of the earth than a sphere  given as  the oblate spheroid which is  sphere+a small amount of a Bessel function or small order?

Comment: I think you might be looking for something like a torus with an inner radius tending to 0.

Comment: ...and if memory serves the opposite would be a Prolate Spheroid ..

Comment: @ancientmathematician does "oblate spheroid" include objects that are in fact pinched at the poles, so that a longitudinal cross section would look like the outline of a Venn diagram?

Comment: I cannot remember! I only recall them as $r=R(1+\epsilon J_k(\cos\theta))$ - does this have dimples at the poles if $\epsilon$ is quite big?

Comment: uh, I'll be honest you've lost me. I'm not *that* good at maths (yet), I was just curious about such a shape.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain what you mean but it could be that you are thinking of a [Spheroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spheroid) or an [Ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid).

I hope this is of help.

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer this horribly phrased question. Looking back I'm not sure what I was thinking describing it so meaninglessly, I attribute that to my dyslexia.

I believe what I was trying to describe was a torus with no hole or, alternatively, something like resembles the Earth's magnetic field as a solid. Would this still constitute a torus? What if it didn't reached zero on the polar longitudes and instead resembled something like a tangerine?